# Windows Store is not loading any page

Tags: windows-10, internet, windows-store

I have Windows 10 v1511 (10.0.10586.0). early windows store was running well but after running the command WSRESET.EXE. Windows store is not loading any page 
I want to tell about two things.

1. I have diabled BITS Service and deleted qmgr.dll.
2. same case with Windows update service (wuaueng.dll)

early even without these services windows store is loading pages very well but facig the problem of downloading(stuck at pause )means automaticaly downloading gets paused when try to resume. but after running this command WSRESET.EXE  windows store neithor loading pages nor downloading with errors like 0x8000ffff and 0x80072EE2

Comment: 0x80072EE2 = ERROR_INTERNET_TIMEOUT so check all network related settings/software (AV suite) and don't use proxys (if you use one)